# Android substring values in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm pulling data from database into an arraylist.  I want to manipulate the arraylist and get a substring of the results.  How can I substring the values generated in carList below?

```
private ArrayList<Cars> carList;
carList = CarDAO.getCarsByEngine(engineType);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. substring would indicate a string but I see none.

Comment: If you mean sublist then just iterate through, copy cars in new list and `null` the original list

Comment: are you looking to combine the results into a single string?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the returned results SUBSTRINGED.  Instead of doing it at backend trying to substring result output on java side.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a attribute String name in car.

```
String searchStr = "your_str";
for(i=0; i<carList.size();i++){
    carList[i].name;
    if(searchStr.toLowerCase().contains(carList[i].name.toLowerCase())){
        // do somethig with your object carList[i]
    }
}
```